# Function written in Python to list files in a specific folder not filtering out unwanted results

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

This function is not filtering out files that match the prefix(~$) or extension (eval(not '.xlsm')) nor is it filtering out folders.

All 3 attempts produced the same result.  I'm pretty new at this Python stuff so please dumb it down for me what I should do...

ATTEMPT 1

```
def list_of_files(folder_path, prefix_to_filter_out, extension_to_filter_out):
    ...
        result = dict([(file, None) for file in os.listdir(folder_path)
                       if os.path.isdir(file) is False and
                       file.startswith(prefix_to_filter_out) is False and
                       file.endswith(extension_to_filter_out) is False])
    ...
    return result
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
def list_of_files(folder_path, prefix_to_filter_out, extension_to_filter_out):
    ...
        result = dict([(file, None) for file in os.listdir(folder_path)
                       if not(os.path.isdir(file)) and
                       not(file.startswith(prefix_to_filter_out)) and
                       not(file.endswith(extension_to_filter_out))])
    ...
    return result
```

ATTEMPT 3

```
def list_of_files(folder_path, prefix_to_filter_out, extension_to_filter_out):
    ...
        result = dict([(file, None) for file in os.listdir(folder_path)
                       if not(os.path.isdir(file))
                       if not(file.startswith(prefix_to_filter_out))
                       if not(file.endswith(extension_to_filter_out))])
    ...
    return result
```

I expect this to filter out temporary files on Google Drive that start with '~$', filter out folders, and filter out anything besides an Excel workbook.
However, it is including everything- even folders.
This is part of an app that pops up a message box anytime a file in a specified folder is added/removed.  This gets annoying really quick because it'll pop up every time someone opens or closes a file in Google Drive.

Thanks for the help!

ATTEMPT 4

```
def list_of_files(folder_path, prefix_to_filter_out, extension_to_focus_on):
    # Example:
    # folder_path = '/Google Drive/Box List/New Jobs',
    # prefix_to_filter_out = '~$',
    # extension_to_focus_on = '.xlsm'
    result = {}
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_path, file)) is True:
            continue
        if file.startswith(prefix_to_filter_out):
            continue
        if not file.endswith(extension_to_focus_on):
            continue
        result[file] = None

    return result
    # Expected result:  {
    # 1741A Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1741B Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1741C Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1742A WIZARD RENOVATIONS.xlsm,
    # 1742B WIZARD RENOVATIONS.xlsm}

    # Actual result:    {
    # 1741A Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1741B Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1741C Tegan Lee.xlsm,
    # 1742A WIZARD RENOVATIONS.xlsm,
    # 1742B WIZARD RENOVATIONS.xlsm
    # ~$1742A WIZARD RENOVATIONS.xlsm}
```

No more subfolders in result, but the prefix is not filtering properly.
This last file is unwanted in the result...  It is a temporary file Google Drive creates when a file is open. 
Yet, when I enter the prefix in manually like so: file.startswith('~$'), it works.  When I print(prefix_to_filter_out) it spits out ~$, so it's not an input error.

Comment: Your third attempt is invalid syntax. Your first should work although `is False` is a very bad way to write a not. Your second solution *does* work. You did *not* provide the inputs you are using nor the outputs you expect. What does "prefix `~?`"? `~?` loooks like a regex but python `startswith` and `endswith` only use substring matching...

Comment: classic issue: `os.path.isdir(file)` is always false because you need to join the directory (file is the filename). Use `os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_path,file))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Eagle eyed.

Comment: `eval(not '.xlsm')` ?? this is probably `false`

Comment: besides why creating a dictionary? use a `set`. You have no values to associate to the files. Please provide a [mcve], or at least the values of the filter parameters / a full call of the function

Comment: @Bakuriu May you explain to me more about the prefix?  The prefix I want filtered out is '~?', which are temporary files Google Drive creates every time a file is currently open.  folder_path = '/Google Drive/Box List/New Jobs' and following Jean's advice I got rid of the eval(), which is more error-prone and changed the name of the variable "extension_to_filter_out" to "extension_to_focus_on"- which now equals '.xlsm' .  The code now looks similar to  Shay's suggestion.  Not sure how to paste it into a comment without it looking all jumbled...  Thank you for your super quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing some of the finer points.

Your `file` variable is the name of a file in `folder_path`, NOT in your working directory. `os.path.isdir` looks for `file` from outside, doesn't find it, then returns `False`.

Let `os.path.isdir` find the directory by giving the whole path `os.path.join(folder_path, file)`.

```
def list_of_files(folder_path, prefix_to_filter_out, extension_to_filter_out):
    result = {}
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_path, file)) is True:
            continue
        if file.startswith(prefix_to_filter_out):
            continue
        if file.endswith(extension_to_filter_out):
            continue
        result[file] = None

    return result    >>> list_of_files("some_directory", "~", ".xlsm") # should work
```

`continue` means "go the the next file".

For what it's worth, multi-line `dict` function calls are a tough way to develop. An easier coding style allows you to incorporate and test these filters one at a time.

If you're not ready to tackle unit tests yet, just run the function from the outside and check the results for one filter at a time:

- folders getting filtered? Yes, let's move on to prefixes.
- prefixes getting filteres? Yes, let's move on to file extensions.
- ...

Comment: Thanks Shay! That's a step in the right direction. I'm not getting folders and I changed extension_to_filter_out to extension_to_focus_on, which is less error-prone without the eval(). However, I'm still getting those darn temporary files in the results (files that start with '~$')

Comment: Have you tried printing the filenames as you loop over them to see exactly what Python is seeing. Sounds like that ~$ might be getting replaced with something else.

Comment: Yes.  I have it currently open now.  It's weird.  When I manually enter it the results are as expected.  The only thing I can think of is that when it imports it from a text file it is adding hidden characters.

Comment: Very wierd, because this works: '~$filename'.startswith('~$') -> True

Comment: Okay.  So I removed any hidden null characters ('\x00') and return characters ('\n') and now it is working great.  Mystery solved...